# Difference between using "of" OR "for"

Tags: prepositions

Im designing an award certificate but not sure how to word it.

> Option 1. Certificate **of** Entrepreneur of the year.

vs.

> Option 2. Certificate **for** the Entrepreneur of the year.

Do I write "Certificate of" or "Certificate for". Can someone help pls.

Comment: As it would be self evident that it was a certificate, I suggest you stick to: **Entrepreneur of the Year**

Comment: Or: Entrepreneur of the Year Certificate

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "Certificate of Entrepreneur of the Year" and "Certificate for the Entrepreneur of the Year" lies in the prepositions "of" and "for," which slightly alter the meaning of the phrases.

"Certificate of Entrepreneur of the Year": This phrase suggests that the certificate itself is called "Entrepreneur of the Year." The focus is on the title of the certificate. This construction might be less common and can sound a bit awkward.

"Certificate for the Entrepreneur of the Year": This phrase indicates that the certificate is being awarded to the person who has been recognized as the Entrepreneur of the Year. The focus is on the purpose of the certificate, which is to honor the recipient. This construction is more common and sounds more natural.

In most cases, it would be preferable to use "Certificate for the Entrepreneur of the Year" as it more clearly conveys the purpose of the certificate and sounds more natural.

Answer (score -1):

They can both be used. But notice:

> Certificate **of** the Entrepreneur of the Year

This sounds as if *certificate* and *entrepreneur of the year* are the same entity.

> Certificate **for** the Entrepreneur of the Year

This one sounds as if *certificate* and *entrepreneur of the year* are **different** entities, different subjects.

Therefore, I'd advise you to use **for**.

Comment: Can you have 2 "the" in the same sentence..like...certificate for THE entrepreneur of THE year?

Comment: Yes, although it sounds redundant. It can be deduced from *Entrepreneur of the year* that there's only one. No need to specify it with an additional **the**. And could you please accept my answer? :)

Comment: I do not understand how *of* says they are the same entity.  I can think of some examples where that's true, but they're all geographic: *village of Anabru*, *island of Sardegna*.